# How can you duplicate, edit, and or reuse a component in Angular that is strictly just html & css?

Tags: html, css, angular, dry

In Angular, I am wanting to reuse a component in about 30+ pages on my website where the majority of the pages are the same regarding the css but the content inside is different. I understand I can just put lets say < app-example ></ app-example > in all the pages while using < ng-content > to project different content inside each component that are the exact same and write the other pages manually in html and css. The problem arises when in the future I want an entirely different css grid setup to show the content, or I want that content inside to not be in a grid at all and to have a position fixed, and or I want to add and design 3 html elements to my html of 1 singular component that is still very similar to the other 30 pages. I feel there is a DRY way of solving this problem by basically creating 1 "default" html Template filled with "placeholders" and a "default" css design so I can put it multiple pages to use as a building block while still being able to edit, add, or remove each "placeholder" with the desired css I want in the new component and or override the "default" css I originally implemented all while never actually touching the original template that contains all the "placeholders" or the "default" css. I would love some feedback, because at this moment I feel like copying & pasting the same html design hundreds of times is the only option. I have played around with ng-content, ng-template, and ngTemplateOutlet a little bit, but I haven't successfully figured out the answer regarding to my problem

I created a quick HTML Template for this example in the stackblitz below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tss4d5?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Please provide more explanation of the stackblitz, i can't see any relation to the question.

Comment: @AviadP. I just made a quick HTML template to save someone the hassle to create a stackblitz if they had a solution to visually solve the problem

Comment: I don't understand your concern - maybe it's me tho... Why can't you use some data structure in memory that represents your content, and then render it using this or that component to get a different visual?

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach would be to use ngSwitchCase so that way you can reuse the same component while producing a different result.  ng-content is not going to do what you want to do.  a switch case is really nested if else statements with a default outlet.

The ngswitch decorator is available from the angular common library and does not require an additional import.

It sounds like this might be a good option for you to review.  If that isn't what you want then one could use directives to inject content as they see fit, but that's much more complex and requires a component factory.

You can read about both of these below:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory

Comment: hmm I will definitely look at ngswitch as I haven't played around with it before. Appreciate the feedback!